# Access Queries in Sub Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know how to open a secondary database from a master database, but how can I switch "focus" to the secondary database and scan through the table names to see if a table exists in that database, if it does delete it?

This is how I would open the database but this seems to only check the database I am running the code in, not the secondary database that is opened.

```
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("exec_Dead")
Set ws = DBEngine(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\Test\Testing.mdb")
On Error Resumse Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, "Late Payments For Today"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an `Access.Application` variable so that you can interact with that instance of Access.

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim tbl as DAO.TableDef
Dim accDB As Access.Application

Set accDB = New Access.Application
accDB.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test\Testing.mdb", false

For each tbl in accDB.CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tbl.Name = "The name of the table you want to delete" then
        accDB.DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tbl.Name
    End If
Next

accDB.CloseCurrentDatabase
set accDB = nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

`DoCmd.DeleteObject` is a method of `Application`, so you would need an `Application` instance for *Testing.mdb* in order to use `DeleteObject`.

You can do that, as @Zaider demonstrated.  However you could just execute a `DROP TABLE` statement from *db* in your existing code:

```vb
Set ws = DBEngine(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("C:\Test\Testing.mdb")
On Error Resumse Next
'DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, "Late Payments For Today"
db.Execute "DROP TABLE [Late Payments For Today];"
```